# Python3.4: Upgrade pandas does not work

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I use the pre-installed python3.4 on Ubuntu 14 and want to upgrade pandas to version 0.18.0:

```
import pandas 
pandas.__version__
>>>>'0.13.1'
```

When I try that it seems that he does not upgrade anything

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade python-pandas
python-pandas is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-de kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

and I still have the same version after the upgrade function call:

```
import pandas 
pandas.__version__
'0.13.1'
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I then tried using

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

and got this error message:

```
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_server/pandas/setup.py';      exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ts_7va4h-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in     /tmp/pip_build_server/pandas
Storing debug log for failure in /home/server/.pip/pip.log
```

when I use

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

there is no error message but there is also nothing upgraded.

It seems one needs a PhD in computer science to get a python 3 package installed.

Comment: Maybe there's simply no newer version in the repositories you're currently using?

Comment: the newest pandas version is '0.18.1' and python 3.4. on my windows pc gives different results than my linux pc. therefore i must upgrade

Comment: *"Maybe there's simply no newer version **in the repositories you're currently using**?"* I.e. do you see  '0.18.1' anywhere when you type `apt-cache policy python-pandas`?

Comment: You are right. 0.13.1 seems to be the latest. How can I change the repository? I am a noob, sorry.

Comment: The convention in Linux land is to place apps into repositories based on their level of stability and maturity. These are often called things like "stable", "unstable", "testing" etc. Using the newest stuff comes with a risk of instability so before adding a repository, try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`. The newest pandas package I could find for Ubuntu 14.x is 0.16.0~ppa16~revno-7407~ubuntu14.04.1 0. Maybe the best way to install is via Anaconda as suggested [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/install.html#installing-pandas-with-anaconda)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue (not being able to update pandas via pip3). The problem is installing pandas from two sources (pip3 and apt-get). Try this (it's what I did on ubuntu 16.04):

1. Remove existing pandas:

   - `sudo apt-get remove python3-pandas`
2. Install via pip3:

   - `sudo pip3 install pandas # it installed pandas 0.18`
3. Check the correct version a terminal (ctr+alt+t) type:

   - `pip3 list # prints out a list of installed python3 modules`

   OR / AND

   - `python3`
   - `import pandas`
   - `pandas.__version__`