# Upgrade Pandas for Python3 not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have python 2 & 3 installed on my system. I am using Ubuntu. Also using the Spyder IDE.
I am trying to upgrade Pandas version in python3 but unable to upgrade pandas in Python3. Currently its pandas 0.17.1

I have tried the following:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
sudo easy_install -U pandas
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

Also followed the instruction given in [Python3.4: Upgrade pandas does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244753/python3-4-upgrade-pandas-does-not-work)

The pandas in Python2 got upgraded to 0.21.1 but have been unable to upgrade pandas in Python3.

Comment: try to execute the `pip3 install --upgrade pandas` on its own

Comment: Already done, I am getting "Requirement already up-to-date"

Comment: How do you check for the version of pandas?

Comment: In Spyder, import pandas and then pandas.__version__ , which gives me 0.17.1 which I am trying to upgrade to atleast 0.18.x so that I can use rolling functions.

Comment: try removing the pandas module and then reinstalling it

Comment: it worked, I had tried it earlier as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244753/python3-4-upgrade-pandas-does-not-work but it did not upgrade and this time it worked. Dont know what different I did this time. Thanks Kessi

Comment: Close this thread then

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the pandas module and then reinstalling it